# Gegenteil von "Identität" - Gibt es eine bessere Übersetzung als "Nichtidentität"?

Tags: translation, single-word-request

Im Englischen wird das Word *non-identity* als Gegenteil zu *identity* verwendet. Meiner Meinung nach ein unglückliches *Antonym*.

Wisst ihr, ob im deutschen Sprachgebrauch das Word *üblich* ist? Google gibt 35.000 Suchergebnisse an; nicht überzeugend.

**Wie würdet ihr das Gegenteil von Identität benennen?** Seid gerne kreativ; bitte mit Erklärung.

**Nachtrag**
Es geht hauptsächlich um eine mathematische/informatische Bezeichnung. Jemand übersetzte das Wort einfach mit *Nichtidentität*. Aber ich bin nicht zufrieden damit; es klingt nicht ganz korrekt.
Der Artikel befindet sich [hier](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Vergleichsoperatoren#Strikte_Ungleichheit_(!)).
Es gibt dort vier Bezeichnungen: Gleichheit, Ungleichheit, Identität (strikte Gleichheit) und *Nichtidentität?* (nicht strikte Gleichheit).

Ich habe gehofft, dass vielleicht jemand mit zweierlei kommen würde:

- Ein gebräuchliches Wort, wo man sagen würde: Ja genau, das passt. Warum bin ich von selbst drauf gekommen?
- Oder ein neues Wort, dessen Gebrauch man einführen könnte.

Im Englischen hat man es sich einfach gemacht: *non-identity*, und dies wird in der Tat in wissenschaftlichen Beiträgen häufig verwendet.
Ich wollte den Bezug zur Wissenschaft nicht erwähnen, um die Kreativität zu fördern; ich wollte mir das passende Wort aussuchen. Aber dies ist wohl ohne Bezug zur Verwendung nicht so leicht.

Comment: Du meinst Identität im Sinne mathematischer Gleichheit?

Comment: meinst du im mathematischen Sinn oder allgemeinumgangssprachlich? Wenn du letzteres meinst, könntest du ein Beispiel geben?

Comment: Ich glaube, es bedarf einer **exakten** Definition, wozu ein Gegenteil suchst. Wiktionary gibt beispielsweise zwei Antonyme, die aber in zwei ganz verschiedene Richtungen gehen: Anonymität, Ähnlichkeit. Wozu suchst du also das Gegenteil?

Comment: Das Gegenteil von "kalt" ist "heiß" aber schon "warm" ist die Verneinung von "kalt". "Identität" ist Gleichheit, die Verneinung dessen ist Ungleichheit, aber das ist nicht das Gegenteil. Das Gegenteil von 7 ist nicht 8. Vielleicht 1/7 oder -7, je nach dem welcher Aspekt betrachtet wird.

Comment: I aktualisiere mal meine Frage.

Comment: Ach, JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es gibt einen Unterschied zwischen dem normalen Sprachgebrauch und der mathematischen Sprache. Ohne Kontext bedeutet „Identität“ ziemlich genau das Gleiche wie “identity” im Englischen.

Im mathematischen Gebrauch bedeutet „Identität“ aber eher/auch [“identity element”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element). Eine andere Übersetzung für “identity element” ist [„Neutrales Element“](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrales_Element). Im mathematischen Sprachgebrauch würde man wohl stets anders formulieren, um dieses Problem zu umgehen. Man würde also eher sagen

> Sei x nicht das neutrale Element in G.
>   Jedes Element, welches nicht das neutrale Element ist, …

statt

> Sei x eine Nichtidentität
>   Jede Nichtidentität …

Die beiden zweiten Beispiele kommen mir sehr ungewöhnlich vor.

Im Gegensatz dazu ist ein Element (in einem Ring), welches nicht invertierbar ist, durchaus als ["Nichteinheit"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einheit_%28Mathematik%29) bekannt.

Im Kontext der Javadokumentation würde ich eher bei dem Punkt „Identität/strikte Gleichheit“ das Wort „Identität“ entfernen. Meine Assoziationen sind da Identität als Persönlichkeit (unpassend) oder Identität als neutrales Element (auch unpassend). Strikte Gleichheit und strikte Ungleichheit sind die passenden Übersetzungen in der Dokumentation.

Comment: Primär bedeutet Identität die Gleichheit zwischen zwei, typischerweise algebraischen, Ausdrücken. Das ist besonders dann von Interesse, wenn die Gleichheit nicht offensichtlich ist. Beispiel: Die Euleridentität ist solch ein nichttrivialer Fall. Siehe https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Euler_identity .

Answer (score 3):

Identität meint eigentlich "Selbigkeit". das ist mehr als "Gleichheit" - vergleiche 'dasselbe' zu 'dasgleiche'. Das Gegenteil von Identität könnte also, will man es nicht schlicht verneinen wie in nicht-identisch, was zweifellos zutreffend ist - in der Betonung der Unterschiedlichkeit liegen. Als Gegenteil von Identität könnte man also "Diversität" ansehen. (so wie bei 'kulturelle Identität' oder 'kulturelle Diversität'.

Comment: "Dasgleiche" ist kein Wort.

Answer (score 1):

Im Werk Theodor W. Adornos spielt der Begriff der Nichtidentität eine große Rolle. Das ist zumindest eine prominente Verwendung des Begriffs in der deutschen Sprache, allerdings ist das Deutsch Adornos in vielerlei Hinsicht speziell. Wenn du das Wort verwendest, würdest du es also zumindest nicht in die deutsche Sprache einführen; vielleicht aber würdest du es in einen neuen Kontext einführen.

Comment: Irgendwie keine Antwort auf die Frage. Das ist doch hier kein Chat. Wenn du wenigstens etwas zu Adornos Begriff der *Nichtidentität* sagen würdest oder was das mit dem Gegenteil von Identität zu tun hat ...

Answer (score 1):

"Verschiedenheit" kann sowohl für Gleichheit als auch für Nicht-Identität verwendet werden. Mathematiker würden aber eher von "Nicht-Identität" und "Unterscheidbarkeit" sprechen. Es gibt allerdings auch die (etwas veralteten) Ausdrucksweisen "numerische Verschiedenheit" und "qualitative Verschiedenheit", dabei wäre "(rein/bloß/nir) numerische Verschiedenheit" die Nicht-Identität des Ununterscheidbaren. Die eigentlich nötige Klammer wird dabei oft weggelassen ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Im mathematischen bzw. logischen Kontext würde ich als Begriffspaare *gleich* und *ungleich* verwenden, alternativ natürlich *identisch* und *ungleich*.
im allgemeineren Sprachgebrauch könnten *Identität* und *Verschiedenheit* bzw. *Unterschiedlichkeit* verwenden.

Comment: Da "Unterschied" bereits für den Grad der "Unterschiedlichkeit" verwendet wird ("Wie groß ist der Unterschied") sähe ich davon im mathematischen Kontext ab. Vorgeschlagenes "ungleich" ist mMn hinreichend.

Comment: @Burki Diesen Gedanken hatte ich ebenfalls. Aber Gleichheit und Ungleichheit wird in dem Kontext schon anderweitig verwendet. Deswegen hoffte ich eine andere Bezeichnung als Ungleichheit zu finden.